# Null pointer exception when checking for permission with android.content.Context.checkPermission

Tags: java, android, android-context, android-permissions

I need to check for permissions before querying the Android calendar for events.
To do it, Android studio is warning that I need to follow a check before querying.
The auto generated code is this piece:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        System.out.println("NO ACCESS TO CALENDAR!! Abort mission, abort mission!!");
    }
```

When trying to run it, I get this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>       android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' 
>       on a null object reference

So it is clear that something is null at this point, and I tried to get the context of the app with a different way, but it's still the same error. 
Other thing I tried was this code, which is supposed to handle the targets lower than Android 6:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
```

Still get the same error, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: from where are you calling this? where this object relate to

Comment: it's a separate class, controller:   public class DummyData extends Activity { .... }

Comment: well you should use this from AppCompatActivity class not form Activity

Comment: tried, still same error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> it's a separate class, controller: public class DummyData extends Activity { .... }

That is not going to work.

**Never** extend `Activity` unless it is a real activity, one that you will register in the manifest.

**Never** create an instance of an `Activity` via a constructor (e.g., the `new DummyData()` that you have somewhere in your code). Use `startActivity()` to display an activity that you have registered in the manifest.

As it stands, while your `DummyData` class may work from a compilation standpoint, it will not work at runtime. An `Activity` needs to be instantiated by the framework, and that is not the case with your `DummyData`.

Pass a *real* `Context` object to `checkSelfPermission()`, and pass a *real* `Activity` object to `requestPermissions()`. In this case, "real" means "handed to you from the framework".

Comment: indeed, it's turns out to be a stupid question, but your answer did help me out. I removed the extends Activity, and passed the context and activity to a constructor. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare As stated *Pass a real Context object to checkSelfPermission(), and pass a real Activity object to requestPermissions()*. Will passing getContext() in Fragment will work? Or I have to use getActivity()?

Comment: @VishalKale: Either of those should work for the purposes of `checkSelfPermission()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use (Activity)mContext instead of this.**

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)mContext,Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)    
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
```

Comment: For the requestPermissions method, it actually still works if you pass the activity. (though you might as well send the context to both for consistency)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the right activity at the position "this"
main problem in activity.

Try to write the code in MainActivity and test.

```
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
}
```